# Which wall charger for Beaglebone Green Wireless?

Tags: power-supply, charger, beaglebone-black, wall-wart, beaglebone

I'm trying to find an appropriate [wall charger](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=wall+charger) to power my Beaglebone Green Wireless (BBGW) through Micro-USB port.

Wall is 220v 50Hz.

[Hardware Overview](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/BeagleBone_Green_Wireless/#hardware-overview) reveals a [TPS65217](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS65217)C Power Management IC (PMIC).

[Parameters](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS65217#product-details##params)

> Iout (Max) (A) 1.2

[Features](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS65217#product-details##features)

> 2-A Output Current on Power Path
> Linear Charger; 700-mA Maximum Charge Current

**Confused. How many Amps are enough?

(α) 5V, at least 1.2A

(β)  5V, at least 2A

(γ) 5V, at least 700mA**

---

[Seeed Studio BeagleBone® Green Wireless](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/BeagleBone_Green_Wireless/) on Seeed Wiki
[SeeedStudio BeagleBone Green Wireless](https://beagleboard.org/green-wireless) on beagleboard.org

Comment: It's not clear why you are asking. Why have you quoted "Iout"? What is the total current required by your modules? You just need a PSU that is capable of providing at least that current.

Comment: @Transistor (1) I've quoted those phrases but have no idea what they mean. This is exactly why I'am asking here. (2) I don't connect anything to BBGW at all. Just the board alone. How many amps do I need?

Comment: I can't see anything on the BeagleBone website that quotes the current consumption of the device. You should ask on their forum, "I am selecting a 5 V PSU for my BeagleBone xxx. What is the maximum current requirement of the device?".